# Error initializing appsync client. invalidAuthConfiguration("AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider cannot be nil.")

Tags: swift, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using AWS amplify to build the backend of my ios application.  I am having an issue initializing appsync client.  I have added Auth to the backend and have signed in but I am getting the following error in the console:

CONSOLE:

```
Error initializing appsync client. invalidAuthConfiguration("AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider cannot be nil.")
```

In AppDelegate:

```
// CONFIGURE AWSAppSync
        do {
            // You can choose your database location if you wish, or use the default
            let cacheConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()
            
            // AppSync configuration & client initialization
            let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: AWSAppSyncServiceConfig(), cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration)
            
            appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
            print("appSyncClient initialise success \n")
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
        }
```

I am just guessing here but 'appSyncConfig' variable should be:

```
let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: AWSAppSyncServiceConfig.init(), cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration, userPoolsAuthProvider: AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider?)
```

But how do i get AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider????

Answer (score 0):

In configuring the AWS AppSync you are missing a step which is adding the class to get the tokens from Cognito User Pools.
Of course, here I assume that you have chosen Cognito User Pool as your default authorization type!

Please let me know if you have any more concerns about to setup amplify GraphQL or whatever!

```
import UIKit
import AWSAppSync
import AWSMobileClient

class MyCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider : AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProviderAsync {
    func getLatestAuthToken(_ callback: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
        AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens { (tokens, error) in
            if error != nil {
                callback(nil, error)
            } else {
                callback(tokens?.idToken?.tokenString, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
   
    var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        //// Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.initializeAppSync()
        return true
    }
    
    func initializeAppSync() {
        do {
            // You can choose the directory in which AppSync stores its persistent cache databases
            let cacheConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()
            
            // Initialize the AWS AppSync configuration
            let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig:
                                                                    AWSAppSyncServiceConfig(),
                                                                  userPoolsAuthProvider: MyCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(),
                                                                  cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration)
            
            // Initialize the AWS AppSync client
            appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
            print("appSyncClient initialise success.")
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```